# Problems popluating nested hash data structure in Perl

Tags: perl, cgi

Trying to create a nested hash in Perl that is populated with entries from a CGI form.

Here is a snippet:

```
my $section = $q->param('section') || undef;
my %data;

if($section) {
    my $prod1part  = $q->param('prod1part') || undef;
    my $prod2part  = $q->param('prod2part') || undef;
    my $prod3part  = $q->param('prod3part') || undef;

    my $prod1name  = $q->param('prod1name') || undef;
    my $prod2name  = $q->param('prod2name') || undef;
    my $prod3name  = $q->param('prod3name') || undef;

    my $prod1price = $q->param('prod1price') || undef;
    my $prod2price = $q->param('prod2price') || undef;
    my $prod3price = $q->param('prod3price') || undef;

    my $dealprice  = $q->param('dealprice') || undef;

    my $dealtype   = $q->param('dealtype') || undef;

    my $id = &generateID();

    #GENERATE DATA STRUCTURE FOR PDF
    $data = {    product1  => { part  => $prod1part,
                                name  => $prod1name,
                                price => $prod1price,
                              },
                 product2  => { part  => $prod2part,
                                name  => $prod2name,
                                price => $prod2price,
                              },
                 product3  => { part  => $prod3part,
                                name  => $prod3name,
                                price => $prod3price,
                              },
             ... and so on ...
            };
}
```

But then when I attempt to dump the data structure to check it:

```
print $q->header(-type=>'text/plain');
print Data::Dumper->new([\%data],[qw/data/])->Indent(3)->Quotekeys(0)->Dump;
```

All I get is an empty data structure!!!

```
$data = {};
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what... Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have:

```
$data = { 
    product1  => { part  => $prod1part,
```

What you probably meant:

```
%data = (
    product1  => { part  => $prod1part,
```

---

That being said, you are repeating yourself quite a lot. Try this instead:

```
my $section = $q->param('section');
my %data;

if($section) {
  for my $item_id ( 1..3 ){
    my $item_data = $data{ 'product' . $item_id } = {};
    for my $attr (qw'part name price'){
      $item_data->{ $attr } = $q->param( 'prod' . $item_id . $attr );
    }
  }

  my $dealprice  = $q->param('dealprice');
  my $dealtype   = $q->param('dealtype');

  my $id = generateID();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared data as a hash

```
my %data;
```

and later you use `$data` as if it was an hash ref

```
$data = { 
    product1  => { part  => $prod1part,
                                name  => $prod1name,
                                price => $prod1price,
                              },
```

Change the `my %data` to `my $data = {}`; The 2nd form defined a hash reference `$ and {}` while the 1st form defined a `hash` (`%`)

Comment: to change `my %data` to `my $data = {}`

Comment: After the modification above, does `print Dumper($data);` return `{}` ( I have never used the form you are using) ?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done wrong is failing to `use strict`.  Turning strictures on would have informed you that the line beginning

```
$data = {    product1  => { part  => $prod1part,
```

implicitly created a new variable, `$data`.  When you later inspect `%data`, you don't find anything there -- because you stashed it elsewhere without noticing.

`%data` and `$data` are different variables.  Assigning to `$data` will not change `%data`.  Inspecting `%data` after changing `$data` is unlikely to do what you want.

To solve this problem, first add

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at the top of the source file; this will likely save you many future trips to Stackoverflow.  Then pick which of `%data` or `$data` to keep.  It probably doesn't make a different which you keep; keeping `$data` has the least effect on the source file, so here's how you would do that:

1. Replace mentions of `%data` and `\%data` with `$data`.

This should put the data where you expect to find it.

For more information about the difference between `%data` and `$data`, see [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).  For information about the difference between `$data = {}` and `%data = ()`, see [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).